# Is there anyway to calculate or get serialization time for displaying in ProgressBar?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, progress-bar, binaryformatter

I use C# .net 4.0 and don't see any possible way to do it, but maybe you know? :)
I do my serialization in that way:

```
public static void SaveCollection<T>(string file_name, T list)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream fs = null;

    try
    {
        fs = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "/" + file_name, FileMode.Create);
        bf.Serialize(fs, list);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        if (fs != null)
            fs.Close();

        string msg = "Unable to save collection {0}\nThe error is {1}";
        MessageBox.Show(Form1.ActiveForm, string.Format(msg, file_name, exc.Message));
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa. You are serializing something so large that you can actually time it on a wall clock? Are you doing XML serialization?

Comment: ehm yes, some of my serializable things can take up to 1 minute and this is binary serialization :) just a lot of objects...

Comment: How large is your object when serialized? (On average?)

Comment: 9Mbs and that takes around 10 seconds for serialization while collection contain 1066 objects of different size. Another example - 19 Mbs and around 30 seconds for serializations, while collection has a lot more objects

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. That's *tiny*. Are you doing something other than BinaryFormatter.Serialize()?

Comment: nothing else :) 9 Mbs and 19 Mbs in different programs with different collection objects. maybe that's why size and time has non linear dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's say you use actually know in advance the size of your object graph, which itself may be difficult, but let's just assume you do :). You could do this:

```
public class MyStream : MemoryStream {
    public long bytesWritten = 0;
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {                
        base.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        bytesWritten += count;
    }

    public override void WriteByte(byte value) {
        bytesWritten += 1;
        base.WriteByte(value);
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
var s = new MyStream();
bf.Serialize(s, new DateTime[200]);
```

This will give you the bytes as they are written, so you could calculate the time using that. Note: it's possible you might need to override a few more methods of the stream class.

Comment: if this works, i think this is the solution! i could do bytesWritten as static member, so i can read how much is written in another thread (MyStream.bytesWritten) that also updates ProgressBar

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use static. I would expose a BytesWritten event that you can subscribe to, that way you could serialize multiple objects in the same process at the same time, but that's for another question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is. My advice would be to time how long it takes to serialize (repeating the measurement several hundred or thousand times), average them, and then use that as a constant for calculating serialization progress.

Comment: i hope there is something else can be done, will wait a little till marking this as accepted :P thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could start a timer that runs at a specific frequency (say 4 times a second, but that really has no bearing on anything but how frequently you want to update progress) that calculates how long data currently has taken to transfer, then estimate the remaining time.  For example:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentBytesTransferred = Thread.VolatileRead(ref this.bytesTransferred);
    TimeSpan timeTaken = DateTime.Now - this.startDateTime;

    var bps = timeTaken.TotalSeconds / currentBytesTransferred;
    TimeSpan remaining = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, (int)((this.totalBytesToTransfer - currentBytesTransferred) / bps));
    // TODO: update UI with remaining
}
```

This assumes you're updating `this.bytesTransferred` on another thread and you're targeting AnyCPU.

Comment: but which way i can know how much bytes is transfered?

Comment: Well, I don't know *how* you're serializing data.  But, usually that done in specific chunks (objects), as each chunk is serialized, update the field `bytesTransferred` (with `Thread.VolatileWrite`, if needed).